# Using lapply with as.data.frame

Tags: r, lapply

df is a list of tables (scaped from html and stored as lists) I want to convert to data frame.

```
as.data.frame(df[1])
```

works no problem. However, both

```
df_2 <- lapply(df, as.data.frame)
```

and

```
df_3 <- lapply(df, function(x) {

as.data.frame(x) 

})
```

fail to convert to data frame:

```
> class(df[1])
[1] "data.frame"

> class(df_2[1])
[1] "list"

> class(df_3[1])
[1] "list"
```

Edit with reproducible example:

```
a <- tribble(
+ ~ x, ~ y,
+ 1, 2
+ )
> b <- tribble(
+ ~ x, ~ y,
+ 3, 4
+ )
> a_list <- as.list(a)
> b_list <- as.list(b)
master_list <- list(a_list, b_list)
a_df <- as.data.frame(master_list[1])

> class(a_df)
[1] "data.frame"
master_df <- lapply(master_list, as.data.frame)
> class(master_df[1])
[1] "list"
class(master_df[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Indeed [[ ]] was needed to filter out container... however this still doesn't solve the whole reason for doing this in my original example, which is to call a function removing empty rows from each table:

```
> clear_empty <- master_df[!apply(master_df == "", 1, all), ]
Error in apply(master_df == "", 1, all) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Maybe I will have to find another function to do this, although I liked the simplicity of the one above.

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example ([mcve])?

Comment: Also `lapply` returns a list. Hard to tell without seeing an example, but you could try extracting the element with `[[` rather than `[`. `[[` extracts the element whereas `[` extracts the element and container (in this case likely a list)

Comment: @MikeH. Indeed, I had forgotten about that.

Comment: @JohnColeman Ok added, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
a <- tribble(
   ~ x, ~ y,
   1, 2,
   1,1,
   '','',
   1,''
   )
b <- tribble(
   ~ x, ~ y,
   3, 4,
   '',2,
   4,''
   )
a_list <- as.list(a)
b_list <- as.list(b)
master_list <- list(a_list, b_list)
nes_list <- lapply(master_list,function(x) { 
  x <- as.tibble(x)
  x[x == ''] <- NA
  # removing rows that have all NA
  # x[rowSums(is.na(x)) != ncol(x),]
  # remove rows that have at least one NA
  # x[complete.cases(x),]
})
```